# JS function Calling from backend giving function undefined error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a JS function.
When I am calling it from link button its working fine. But When I am calling it from backend The error is function is undefined.
Why is that happening?
Do I need to register it first in Pageload event and then after that in the required function?
This LOC is in the required function. I have not registered script in Pageload as I didnt needed it there.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), script, "displayGrade(); ", true);
            if(!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(script))
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), script, "displayGrade(); ", true);
```

My script function has only one line

```
 <script>
        function displayGrade()
    {
           document.getElementById('idGrade').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean call the function from backend since i see the function will manipulate DOM? And what function is undefined?

Comment: @MudOnTire... Error : Script function displayGrade() is undefined when calling from a function from the code behind.  
                                                             
                               Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock( this.GetType(), script, "displayGrade(); ", true);
                                                   if(!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(script))
                                                             
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock( this.GetType(), script, "displayGrade(); ", true);

Answer (score 0):

I made the div a server element and Now I am changing the property of div from code behind without need of javascript.

C#:

```
int level = TreeMenuView1.SelectedNode.Depth;
        if(level==0)
        {div1.Style.Add("display", "block");}
```

Comment: But then also I want to understand why I wasn't able to call JS function from backend successfully. If  anyone on this forum can explain why this kind of error occured. then I will be saved for future JS issues. Again for Reference the error was - JS function is undefined when called from code behind

Comment: Is that possible you should pass the name 'displayGrade' as the parameter instead of 'displayGrade()' ? Because i read the official document, they pass the function name..

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), script, "displayGrade", true);
                if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(script)) ;
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), script, "displayGrade",true); Still the same error - displayGrade is undefined

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750(v=vs.110).aspx. you can follow the official example and try again. that's all i can help for now, since i have never used this feature..

Comment: Sure... I will try that way.... And I am sorry.. I forgot to answer your first question. I needed to call JS functions from code behind because I want to use this function on click event like tree node change.